# Read line by line and write in another file shell script

Tags: shell

I have a file called "test_file1". I want to read each line of this file and write it to another file called "test_file2". Both of these files are in the same directory.

I tried

```
#!/bin/sh
# My first Script
echo "Hello World!"
file=$(<test_file1.txt)
echo "Test" >> test_file2.txt 
while IFS= read -r line;do
    echo -e "legendary" >> test_file2.txt
    echo "$line" >> test_file2.txt
done <"$file"
echo "completed"
```

The script writes "Test" into test_file2.txt but does not write 'legendary' or the lines in test_file1 into test_file2.

Can someone please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the file directly instead of first reading it into an array; to do that change your
 `done <"$file"` to `done < "test_file1.txt"`

```
#!/bin/sh
# My first Script
echo "Hello World!"
echo "Test" >> test_file2.txt 
while IFS= read -r line;do
    echo -e "legendary" >> test_file2.txt
    echo "$line" >> test_file2.txt
done < "test_file1.txt"
echo "completed"
```

Comment: Hi DAXaholic, 
    Thank you. Works fine now.!!

Comment: It would be much more efficient to do a single redirection after `done` than to repeatedly open and close the file within the loop. Better still would be to replace this with a srmple Awk script; a shell loop to read and write lines like this is frequently an antipattern.

Comment: Of course it would be more efficient to write an awk script - it would be even more efficient to write a native application in C :)
If this script is going to process thousands of lines then I agree and it probably should be refactored. In this case I just assume (bc of lacking infos) that there are no such tight perf constraints and therefore IMHO it is better to show the questioner the failing parts of his own code instead of giving him a complete new code snippet (maybe even in a different language) which maybe is hard to understand. That said, nevertheless thx for the additional note!